# Finite generation of homology of total space with nontrivial local coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $F\to E\to B$ be a Serre fibration such that the (integral) homology of $F$ and $B$ are finitely generated in each degree. Must the homology of $E$ also be finitely generated in each degree?

If $\pi_1 B$ acts trivially on $H_*(F)$ then this can be shown by looking at the  $E^2$-page of the Serre spectral sequence. For instance, this is lemma 1.9 of Hatcher's [Spectral Sequences & Algebraic Topology](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/SSAT/SSATpage.html). I am interested if this is still true if we remove this condition about the $\pi_1 B$-action, but I am less comfortable working with the local homology groups that appear.

[This similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254029/serre-classes-and-the-serre-spectral-sequence) asked whether this is true for any Serre class if you consider only positive-degree homology groups. An answer by William showed that it is not for the Serre class of finte abelian groups. I am interested in the Serre class of finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: You might want to look at Chapter 20 in tom Dieck's book, which avoids the Serre spectral sequence.

Comment: @VincentBoelens thanks for the reference! It seems like 20.5.3(1) is the statement regarding homology in a Serre class for fibrations with a general base. However, it makes the assumption that the Serre class is saturated (i.e., closed under arbitrary sums), which I'm afraid doesn't hold for finitely generated abelian groups.